# Symfony Routing Regex: How to write an optional character?

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I just have a little trouble with the symfony regex pattern in a routing config.

I would like to match both `/keyword` and `/keyword/` URLs. The `/` character is optional.
Here is my pattern :

```
pattern:  /{keyword}/?
```

`/keyword/` matches the pattern, while `/keyword` does not.

How should I write the pattern ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the trailing slash, it is optional — a user will be redirected from the path without the slash to the path with it. So, the `/{keyword}/` pattern will work for both `/{keyword}` and `/{keyword}/`.

However, if you define it without the trailing slash — `/{keyword}` — it will work for `/{keyword}` only.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I noticed that the /keyword url was requesting a 301 redirection towards /keyword/. It seems to be quite good for SEO :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a RegEx pattern in a route. The `keyword` can be required to have a specific RegEx pattern, but that's a different matter.

If you're using YML, then I think the best thing to do is to have two different routes:

```
route1:
    pattern: /{keyword}
    ...

route2:
    pattern: /{keyword}/
    ...
```

If you're using annotations, you can put them both at the top of the controller action:

```
/**
* @Route("/{keyword}");
* @Route("/{keyword}/");
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller where your function is use the annotations :

```
/**
 * Function
 * 
 * 
 * @Route("your/route/{keyword}")
 * @Route("your/route/{keyword}/")
 */
```

And you'll be able to access to this function with both routes.

Comment: Do not create a second route. "@Route("acme/{keyword}/") is sufficient.